# Crooked Apple iMac M1 Display

Tags: display, imac, apple-silicon

I ordered the new iMac in blue and found it had a slightly tilted display, about 3mm to the left, so I returned it and ordered it in yellow. After receiving it yesterday I noted that the yellow iMac is also slightly crooked, also 3mm to the left. Are there any customers out there, who got the new iMac with a straight and level mounted monitor, or are all tilted to some degree? Just for fun, is this a design feature or did Apple screw up production and design?

Comment: Looking at a silver one, first batch, arrived day of release. Absolutely no issues. Wanna post a photo?

Answer (score 1):

I heard that is was a QC issue with the iMac. Here is a 9to5 Mac article: https://9to5mac.com/2021/06/14/customers-complain-about-m1-imac-being-shipped-with-crooked-stand/

Comment: To me it would matter whether it is possible to get one that is not crooked. Are, for example, all iMacs which are crooked sent to Germany and it will make no sense to return it, because the next one I order will be crooked as well? I first ordered the cheapo and the second one was the middle model. If I order the high end model, would it be crooked, too?

Comment: I dont think its based on location, I don't know the best way to aim to get a straight one.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any concerns about the quality of a brand new Mac, you should take it back to the shop where you bought it for a replacement or refund.

If you are concerned about the replacement being similarly defective, then you should open it in the shop in the presence of staff.

I'd say getting two in a row is extreme bad luck: third time should be fine!